# Duplicating a sprite

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having trouble with getting new sprites to be added. I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
def duplicate(sprites):
    for d in sprites:
        if d.energy >= d.max_energy * 0.9:
            d.energy = d.energy / 2
            new_d = d.duplicate()
```

so if 1 sprite had its 'energy' above 90% of its 'max_energy', its energy would be cut in half and now there would be a second sprite that was identical to the first. I'm not sure how to pull that off though.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you need to implement the `duplicate` method and construct a new instance of the *Sprite* object in the method.

Another solution is to use the Python [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module. `deepcopy` can create a deep copy of an object. Unfortunately this cannot be used for [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects, as the`image` attribute is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), which cannot be copied deeply. Therefore, a `deepcopy` of a *Sprite* will cause an error.
Unless you have nor any other attribute that needs to be copied deeply, you can make a shallow `copy` of the *Sprite*. The `rect` attribute is a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. The copy of the *Sprite* needs its own rectangle, so you have to generate a new rectangle instance. Fortunately a `pygame.Rect` object can be copied by [`pygame.Rect.copy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.copy):

```
import copy
```

```py
new_d = copy.copy(d)
new_d.rect = d.rect.copy()
```