# Pygame can't create deepcopy of instance

Tags: python, pygame

I have a class to manage **Scenes -> { Menu, Gameplay, GameOver }** in pygame and if the user wants to restart the game, instead of resetting all the variables, I try to create new instances from the instances of the scenes, but I can't compress the pygame surface

*Scenes Management Class*

```
class Game(object):
def __init__(self, screen, states, start_state):
    self.done = False
    self.screen = screen
    self.states = states
    self.state_name = start_state
    self.state = self.states[self.state_name]
    self.new = self.create_copy()

def create_copy(self):#Create new instance from another instance
    liste = {}
    for key, value in self.states.items():
        liste[key] = copy.deepcopy(value)
    return liste

def flip_state(self):
    current_state = self.state_name
    next_state = self.state.next_state
    self.state.done = False
    self.state_name = next_state
    self.state = self.states[self.state_name]

def update(self, dt):
    elif self.state.done:#Change instance when scene is done
        self.flip_state()
        self.states[self.state_name] = self.new[self.state_name]
    self.state.update(dt)

def run(self):#Main processing
    while not self.done:
        pass
```

**I call my main class, but when i call my class i get an error**

```
states = {
    "MainMenu": MainMenu(),
    "OptionsMenu": OptionsMenu(),
    "CreditsMenu": CreditsMenu(),
    "Gameplay": Gameplay(),
    "GameOver": Retry_Menu()
}

game = Game(screen, states, "MainMenu")
game.run()
```

> rv = reductor(4)
> TypeError: can't pickle pygame.Surface objects

**How can I create an instance of my class from another instance?**

Comment: it's not a recurring problem it's a new problem encountered here. @Rabbid76

Comment: You cannot deep copy `pygame.Surface` objects. See [Duplicating a sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377099/duplicating-a-sprite/64377800#64377800).

Comment: then what method should I implement to create new instances of the classes assuming the class has an unknown number of props

Comment: A deep copy will copy all the current state of the object. This is not what you want. You want to restart with the initial states. All you have to do is to create new object. What's wrong with `game = Game(screen, states, "MainMenu")`?

Comment: This seems to be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: yes, that's what I'm talking about, how can I arrange the architecture of my class accordingly. I can't access the props classes so I'm trying to create new instances from instances. how can i build my class so that class architecture can access props classes, anything will help

Comment: What are the "prop classes" and why can't you access them?

Comment: i can access these classes but doing it manually wouldn't make sense and is not good for my class's architecture exp : `if states[state_name] == "Game: states[state_name] = Game()"`

Answer (score -1):

You can copy pygame surface by:

```
surface.copy()
```

So you can change your create_copy function to this:

```
liste = {}
for key, value in self.states.items():
    if isinstance(value, pygame.Surface)
        new = value.copy()
    else:
        new = copy.deepcopy(value)
    liste[key] = new
return liste
```

Comment: While this code is absolutely correct, it may not solve the problem. The question is *"if the user wants to restart the game, ..."*. Copying the object with all of its current states is therefore not a solution.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I assumed that the code is a sketch of real one and Django asked how to copy object containing surface. Why I think that this code is not the one running by Django? 1) incorrect class indent (syntax error) 2) update function has if starting with elif statement (syntax error)

Comment: Possible. However, your answer does not solve the problem. It's a nice answer with a nice snippet of code. However, it is not the answer to this question *"...  if the user wants to restart the game, instead of resetting all the variables, I try to create new instances ..."*