# How to completely copy a class instance in Python? copy.deepcopy doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame, copy

Let's say I have a simple python class, such as

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = pygame.image.load(b)
```

I want to make a function that copies everything inside of this class. The problem I face is that when I use `copy.deepcopy(<class instance>)`, since the paremeter is a `pygame.Surface` object, it cannot copy with that function. How could I make a function that creates a *new* class instance and stores the pointer to it in a *new* variable?

EDIT:
It would be preferable to have a simple property, such as

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = pygame.image.load(b)
    @property
    def clone(self):
        <code to copy>
```

Comment: There is no 100% general way to copy objects. If there were, `copy.deepcopy` would use it.

Comment: You cannot deepcopy a `pygame.Surface` object. No way.  See [Duplicating a sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377099/duplicating-a-sprite/64377800#64377800).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `deepcopy` a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object, however a `pygame.Surface` has a [`copy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy) method. See [Duplicating a sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377099/duplicating-a-sprite/64377800#64377800).

The problem with your code is that you load the `Surface` in the objects constructor. This is bad practice and is causing your problems. Load image at in initialization and pass the image to the objects constructor. Use a `@staticmethod` if you want to encapsulate the loading of the file in the class:

```
class A():
    @staticmethod
    def new():
        image = pygame.image.load('my_image_file.png')
        return A(image)

    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image

    def clone(self):
        return A(self.image.copy())
```

```py
a = A.new()
copy_of_a = a.clone()
```

Anyway there is absolutely no need to copy a `pygame.Surface`. Typically a `surface` is static and does not change at all. It only stores the graphical representation of an object and no other information. So many objects can share the same `Surface` object. You don't have to copy the `Surface`, just share it, which saves a lot of memory and improves performance:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
    def clone(self):
        return A(self.image)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to notice that it is not coincidence. You usually don't want to copy images, because it takes a lot of memory.

If you still want to then:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = pygame.image.load(b)

    # @property is not good here. Keep it as a method
    def copy(self):
        c = copy.deepcopy()
        # pygame.Surface.copy method
        c.b = self.b.copy()
        return c
```